# Height of div increase with relative div

Tags: html, css, height, auto-increment

I have parent div, inside of parent div i have two child both have property **diplay:inline-block**.
When content increase in the right side child then right side child height automatically adjust but left side child height not adjust

Here is my code structure

```
<div class="maskbody">
  <div class="leftchild"></div>
  <div class="rightchild"></div>
</div>
```

Here is my css

```
.maskbody
 {
   width: 600px;
   height: auto;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
   top: 25%;
   background-color: #fff;
}

.leftchild
 {
   display: inline-block;
   background-color:red;
 }

 .rightchild
 {
   display: inline-block;
   background-color:#fff;
 }
```

So i want that if the rightchild content is increases then leftchild height is automatically increases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `display:table-cell` instead `display:inline-block`.

```
 .leftchild
{
 display: table-cell;
 background-color:red;
}

.rightchild
{
display: table-cell;
background-color:green;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/f631uczg/)

Comment: Thanks Suresh but i want to be compatible with every browser. it is possible be these property

Comment: why not?? did you try that?

Comment: No i did not try yet. I am just asking about the browser compatiblity. Is this property works on every browser ?

Comment: sorry Kushal. It is very basic question and we have lot of question similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

Add a empty div with class clear( )  after rightchild div but inside maskbody div.
Then ad this in CSS:
.clear{ clear: both;}

Answer (score 0):

Or use One more option.....

HTML

```
<div class="maskbody">
   <div class="leftchild">
      <p> demo text demo text demo text </p>
      <p> demo text demo text demo text </p>
      <p> demo text demo text demo text </p>
   </div>
   <div class="rightchild">

   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.maskbody {
   width: 600px;
   height: auto;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
   top: 25%;
   background-color:green;  
 }
 .leftchild {
   background-color:red;
   width:50%;
   float:left;
 }
.rightchild {
  width:50%;
  float:left;
 }
```